# Display google map directions when page load

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

At the moment i have an ionic app, and with angular i created a map that give directions from current user location to a predefined address, if user press "get directions". I will like to display the directions when page load without having to press that button.

This is the controller:

```js
 .controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, $ionicPopup, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  // uiGmapGoogleMapApi is a promise.
  // The "then" callback function provides the google.maps object.
  uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51139, -0.2237284);
   var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   // directions object -- with defaults
   $scope.directions = {
    origin: "",
    destination: "12 High Street Kensington",
    showList: false
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

   // instantiate google map objects for directions
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

   $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    $cordovaGeolocation
     .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
     .then(function (pos) {
      map.setCenter((51.498265, -0.313515));
      var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
       
       map: map
      });
      geocoder.geocode({
       latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)
      }, function (responses) {
       if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        $scope.directions.origin = responses[0].formatted_address;
       } else {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
         title: 'Cannot determine address at this location!',
         template: 'Please try again!'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function (res) {
         console.log('Cannot determine address at this location!');
        });
       }
      });
     }, function (err) {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Unable to find your location!',
       template: 'Please try again!'
      });
     });

   });
   $scope.map = map;
   // get directions using google maps api
   $scope.getDirections = function () {
    var request = {
     origin: $scope.directions.origin,
     destination: $scope.directions.destination,
     travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
     if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsList'));
      $scope.directions.showList = true;
     } else {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Cannot find address at this location!',
       template: 'Please try again!'
      });
      alertPopup.then(function (res) {
       console.log('Google route unsuccesful! Please try again!');
      });
     }
    });
   }
  });
 })
```

```html
 <div class="panel-body">
    
    
     <div id='map' data-tap-disabled="true">
     </div>
     
     <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
       <span class="input-label">Origin Address (A)</span>
       <input type="text" id="origin" placeholder="Origin address" ng-model="directions.origin"/>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
       <span class="input-label">Destination Address (B)</span>
       <input type="text" id="destination" placeholder="Destination address" ng-model="directions.destination"/>
      </label>
     </div>
     <div class="pad10">
      <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="getDirections()">Get Directions</button>
     </div>
     <div id="directionsList" ng-show="directions.showList" class="pad10"></div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

When i try your code i get the following message in console:

```
getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.
ionic.bundle.js:20306 TypeError: map.setCenter is not a function
    at $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition.then.$ionicPopup.alert.title (controllers.js:306)
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:21888)
    at ionic.bundle.js:21904
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22916)
    at ionic.bundle.js:23139
    at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:13604)
    at ionic.bundle.js:13984(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:20306
services.js:65 user Id = c621662e-7389-4c4f-9677-35c1e126f6be
2controllers.js:356 Google route unsuccesful! Please try again!
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe call getDirection in your init promise?

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, $ionicPopup, $cordovaGeolocation) {
    // uiGmapGoogleMapApi is a promise.
    // The "then" callback function provides the google.maps object.
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51139, -0.2237284);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // directions object -- with defaults
        $scope.directions = {
            origin: "",
            destination: "12 High Street Kensington",
            showList: false
        };
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        // instantiate google map objects for directions
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            $cordovaGeolocation
                .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
                .then(function (pos) {
                    $scope.map.setCenter((51.498265, -0.313515));
                    var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),

                        map: $scope.map
                    });
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)
                    }, function (responses) {
                        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                            $scope.directions.origin = responses[0].formatted_address;
                        } else {
                            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                                title: 'Cannot determine address at this location!',
                                template: 'Please try again!'
                            });
                            alertPopup.then(function (res) {
                                console.log('Cannot determine address at this location!');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    $scope.getDirections();
                }, function (err) {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Unable to find your location!',
                        template: 'Please try again!'
                    });
                });

        });

        // get directions using google maps api
        $scope.getDirections = function () {
            var request = {
                origin: $scope.directions.origin,
                destination: $scope.directions.destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map);
                    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsList'));
                    $scope.directions.showList = true;
                } else {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Cannot find address at this location!',
                        template: 'Please try again!'
                    });
                    alertPopup.then(function (res) {
                        console.log('Google route unsuccesful! Please try again!');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Tx for answer. I may do something wrong, but no matter how i implement your idea the app is not working anymore. Can you put the js code together?

Comment: you can also try to include ng-init="getDirections()"  in you main controler tag. can you show the error you have?

Comment: is like all the external libraries are not loaded anymore... is quite common when i do some mistakes in the code. The problem is i m quite new to angular and js so i don t really know where to put your code. :(

Comment: for debug use this url in chrome : chrome://inspect/#devices, you can acces  a web console to see your log. for more info use $log service  $log.debug(yourVar) He can help you a lot

Comment: well i get this error in console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
But i m sure this is just becausei don t know where to put your code.

Comment: i have edit my answer with full code, say me if it fix error

Comment: i've updated my question... too many comments here apparently

Comment: map.setCenter is not a function beacuse map is publish on $scope. i have edited the code, sry for mistake...

Comment: Tx for your answer... the problem is that now i can t locate the user anymore. Sometimes in browser is working but never on real devices or emulators. In console i get : Error: latlngbound is not defined